# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when using Warden after authentication

Tags: ruby, rack, warden

I have the following super basic rack application using warden as authentication.

```
require 'rack/router'
require 'warden'
require 'ostruct'
require 'mustache'

class BadAuthenticationEndsUpHere
  def call(env)
    Rack::Response.new(
      Mustache.render('<form method="post"><input name="username" /><input type="password" name="password" /><input type="submit" />'),
      200,
      {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}
    )
  end
end

module PowerNineStore
  class Routes
    def routes
      Rack::Builder.new do
        use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session'

        use Warden::Manager do |manager|
          manager.default_strategies :password
          manager.failure_app = BadAuthenticationEndsUpHere.new
        end

        Warden::Strategies.add(:password) do
          def valid?
            params['username'] && params['password']
          end

          def authenticate!
            if params['username'] == 'foo' && params['password'] == 'bar'
              success!(OpenStruct.new(:username => 'foo'))
            else
              fail!('could not login')
            end
          end
        end

        Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
          OpenStruct.new(:username => 'foo')
        end

        router = Rack::Router.new
        router.post('/session' => lambda { |env|
          env['warden'].authenticate!
          Rack::Response.new('authenticated!', 200, {'Location' => '/session'})
        })

        router.get('/session' => lambda { |env|
          env['warden'].authenticate!

          Rack::Response.new('authenticated!')
        })

        run router
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try and authenticate, I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:287:in `set_cookie_header!'
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:362:in `set_cookie'
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:350:in `commit_session'
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
```

It seems `headers` is nil, but I'm not sure why. I think I set everything up properly according to the documentation, but I must have missed something. Anyone know what it is? I see the login page from the `BadAuthenticationEndsUpHere` class. I get this error after posting the form.

Answer (score 1):

This was because I was using `Rack::Response` as the response from the rack application, and not a normal rack response array. I've filed a bug with Warden to address it.